# Many unexpected CloudWatch Log Streams for EKS control plane components

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster up & running, with everything going smoothly. However, I see there are several unexpected Log streams for the EKS control plane components in CloudWatch.

[image: Many Log streams for EKS control plane component]

I've looked at the AWS/EKS docs and failed to find the *reason* behind this behavior, and how to *change* it to have only one Log stream per control plane component.

In case it helps, here's a little bit of extra context:

- **Kubernetes version**: v1.21
- **Control Plane Logging**:

  - **API server**: Enabled
  - **Authenticator**: Enabled
  - **Scheduler**: Disabled
  - **Audit**: Enabled
  - **Controller manager**: Disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected as per the official [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html#viewing-control-plane-logs):

> As log stream data grows, the log stream names are rotated. When
> multiple log streams exist for a particular log type, you can view the
> latest log stream by looking for the log stream name with the latest
> Last Event Time.

Comment: Completely missed it. It was crystal clear on the docs. Thanks!